# How to test ESRI ArcGIS JavaScript API map interactions with Cypress

Tags: cypress, arcgis-js-api

I have an application where I need to drag and drop point-graphics on a map. I have an event attached on the drag point that updates the state of the component with the new point-graphic location data.

I am using Cypress.io to test the map (ESRI ArcGIS JavaScript API) interactions. I can get `cy.get('canvas').click()` to work and click on the map, but I cannot get a simulated drag and drop events to work on the map. I have tried using the cypress trigger action `cy.get('canvas').trigger('mousedown')` but it will not fire on the map, even `cy.get('canvas').trigger('click', {force:true})` will not work.

Is there a workaround for the drag and drop events for cypress?